# Determining PPT Table dimensions

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm opening an existing PPT deck from Excel using VBA. I'm editing the cell contents, but I need to determine if I need to add rows or columns depending on my Excel content. How can I determine how many cells wide and tall are in the existing PowerPoint table?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a reference to the table shape object as oShp this this will give you the number of rows and columns in the table:

```
Dim intTableRows As Integer, intTableCols As Integer
intTableRows = oShp.Table.Rows.Count
intTableCols = oShp.Table.Columns.Count
```

Try it using the immediate window when you have a table selected:

```
?ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Table.Rows.Count
```

Comment: i'm a new user - i don't have 15 points yet - i'll upvote when i do - maybe upvote my question and i'll get points then