How to check if there is table with only one row on PowerPoint presentation slide and how to delete the slide containing such table?
There is PowerPoint presentation. I need to search slides containig table that consists of one row and delete such slides. How to do it?
P.S. I'm sorry for such a stupid question, guys, but there is a project (about 50 000 lines) full of sh*tty code written not by me. The program generates presentations. I found about 3 reasons why such slide can appear in the presentations, and I fixed them all. Such slides still are in presentations, and I need to fix the problem fast(

Find all tables in presentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240631/select-all-tables-in-power-point-slide How many rows in a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921084/determining-ppt-table-dimensions

Something like this:
Sub DeleteOneRowTables()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long
Dim oSl As Slide

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For x = oSl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With oSl.Shapes(x)
            If .HasTable Then
                If .Table.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    .Delete
                End If  ' Rows count
            End If  ' has table
        End With
    Next    ' x

Next    ' Slide

End Sub

